# hovering on border not on menu

Tags: html, css, wordpress

hey i made a menu on wordpress but the problem that it hover and click on list item only while hovering on the border bottom not on the word

header.php

```
<?php
/**
 * The Header
 *
 * Displays all of the <head> section and everything up till <div id="main">
 *
 * @package Cryout Creations
 * @subpackage parabola
 * @since parabola 0.5
 */
 ?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
<?php  cryout_meta_hook(); ?>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />
<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11" />
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>" />
<?php
    cryout_header_hook();
    wp_head(); ?>
</head>
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>

<?php cryout_body_hook(); ?>

<div id="wrapper" class="hfeed">

<?php cryout_wrapper_hook(); ?>

<div id="header-full">

<header id="header" >

<?php cryout_masthead_hook(); ?>
<div class="header_end">
<div class="header_bottom" >
        <div id="masthead" >
<ul id="branding" role="banner" >

            <li>    <?php cryout_branding_hook();?></li>
            <li>    <?php cryout_header_widgets_hook(); ?></li>



</ul>
<div class="menu_header">
<nav  role="navigation" #id="link-center">

                <?php cryout_access_hook();?>
            </nav><!-- #access -->
</div>
</div>


<br>
        </div><!-- #masthead --><br>

    <div style="clear:both;height:1px;width:1px;"> </div>
<div class="slideshow">
    <?php 
    echo do_shortcode("[metaslider id=5]"); 
?>
</div>
</header><!-- #header -->
</div><!-- #header-full -->
<div id="main">
    <div  id="forbottom" >
        <?php cryout_forbottom_hook(); ?>

        <div style="clear:both;"> </div>

        <?php cryout_breadcrumbs_hook();?>
```

the css part for menu classes :

```
.menu_header nav
{
    float:left;
        width: 714px;
    height: 53px;
    padding:0px;
    list-style:none;
        color: #d9d1c1;
        margin-left: 95px;

}

.menu_header ul li
{
    float:left;
           margin-top: -30px;


}

.menu_header ul li a
{
   float: left;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
        color: #f1ec4b;
            font-size: 24px;
             padding-left: 9px;
    padding-right: 9px;
    margin-left: 9px;
       line-height: 30px;
           border-bottom: 3px solid #f1ec4b;


}

.menu_header ul li a:hover
{
    color: #fff;
}
.menu_header ul li:hover
{
    color: #fff;
}
.menu_header ul li a p {
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #f1ec4b;

}
```

when i tried to remove the border of the link the links is damaged , i don't know exactly what makes hovering only on the border ?

Comment: Can you please provide URL so I can take a look at the source code directly?

Comment: @June that's the URL " http://reload.fakragroup-eg.com/ "

Comment: here is the URL  reload.fakragroup-eg.com

Answer (score 0):

The HTML structure and css code is completely wrongly written , to get you started I have rectfied alot to get the menu to atleast WORK

```css
#branding {
width:200px;
}

.menu_header{
margin-left:0;
width: 724px;
margin-top: 80px;
}
.menu_header nav{
width:auto;
margin-left:0;
}
.header_end{
height:auto;
margin-top:0;
}
.menu_header ul li{
margin-top:0;
}
```

Please add this to very end of the file, Obviously it will change look and feel but there isnt much can be done when the html is not firm

Comment: i tried to add the code but still i have the same problem , the menu works already but items clicked only from the border

Comment: try adding it to very bottom of style.css

Comment: I am adding the code at the run time and it seems to be working for me